# HTML and CSS how to stop elements rearranging?

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a website that look like this in full window mode:

[Before resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knzIh.png)

[After resizing window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iueF8.png)

As you can see everything in the first photo looks good. However in the second photo everything looks good except for the navigation buttons(home, timeline, log in etc). I dont know why they want to resize. I would prefer them to not render like the rest of the html below it. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you set the width of navbar to 100% ?

Comment: yes i did do that

Comment: @ArpitSvt but I also tried 100vw and it didnt work

Comment: @ArpitSvt position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;

Comment: `min-width` to the rescue.